# Firefox floated elements require DOM poke

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-float

I have two elements that are floated left.  One is the first child of the body, and the other is the first child of a container that is the second child of the body.

```
...
<body>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='child'></div>
    </div>
</body>
...
```

The container has a fixed width and is centred using 'margin: 0 auto;'.  The intention was to allow the container child to stay left but accommodate the body child when the window is small.

The fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mrSav/7/

This solution works fine in Chrome; you'll notice that the container child happily moves over for the body child when you make the window smaller.

However in Firefox when you make the window smaller the container child overlaps the body child.

For both children I added a hover state which effectively 'pokes the DOM' and forces Firefox to re-flow the page.  When you hover the mouse over the children the page corrects itself and the children snap into the 'correct' position.

Is this a bug?  Is there a work-around?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, unless this is an editor error.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox both behave the same for me - the two divs overlap in both. Even after adding the closing div tag and using double-quotes.

Comment: @Diodeus Thanks, I corrected it.  Problem remains.

Comment: @brouxhaha Interesting.  I'm using Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on Mac OS X.  I've clarified the JSFiddle example so that the container doesn't overlap- perhaps that was confusing.

Comment: @brendan there we go, now I'm seeing what you described. That's pretty interesting.

Comment: What's also interesting is that the container doesn't actually correct itself with the hover, just the child div inside it does: http://jsfiddle.net/mrSav/8/.

Comment: @brouxhaha It's because the container has a negative z-index, so the hover event is actually captured by the body (I think).  Don't worry about that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - *Container does flow under first child of body*
Still using media-queries, but changing a few things to allow absolute positioning of the container child relative to the window instead of parent: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrSav/13/)**

Remove `position: relative` from container. Separate the two `child` divs css  and change a few styles on the container child like this:

```
.child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px dashed black;
    margin: 0px;
}

body > .child {
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container > .child {
    position: absolute; //relative to window since parent has no position
    left: 100px;
}
```

Then use media-query above 700px to change position to relative and left to auto:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .container > .child {
        position: relative; //override absolute position
        left: auto; //override left: 100px
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL** - *Container doesn't flow under first child of body.*
I have no idea what is causing this (I would guess it's the one floated item being taken out of the flow treated differently by Firefox), but here's a work around using media-queries: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrSav/10/)**

With fixed widths, you can do something like this:

```
.container { //use margin-left: 100px until the total width of the window is 700px (500px + 100px + 100px = container width + 100px on either side )
    margin: 0 0 0 100px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) { //700px to account for 100px of left div (.container is centered at this size)
    .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

I would also add `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` (with appropriate prefixes, -moz-, -webkit-) to account for any borders/padding.

Comment: This solution doesn't provide the *exact* same behaviour: the container should be able to pass through the body child.  You can see the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/mrSav/11/.  BUT- I really like this solution.  Pending....

Comment: I see, I didn't realize you wanted the container to flow underneath. I've updated my answer for this option as well.

Comment: Nice!  Accepted answer.  But...in the end I told the designer it wasn't possible so we just changed the design ;)